# Generate Oracle's SYS_GUID() like in PHP

Tags: php, oracle

I have some entities coming from an Oracle Database which uses SYS_GUID generated ids, I want to know if it is possible to generate similar identifiers using PHP for my new entities.

Of course, I don't have access to the DB, I need to create them using PHP only.

Update: I am using a Linux env

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate a new GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21671179/how-to-generate-a-new-guid)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP function to generate v4 UUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040240/php-function-to-generate-v4-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Just use PHP function [com_create_guid](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-create-guid.php)

Comment: PHP Manual > Function Reference > **Windows Only Extensions** > COM > COM Functions