# Generate unique ids

Tags: php, hash

I am looking for the most reliable way to generate unique ids for a project where users can post content without getting duplicates. When the post is submitted I would like to generate a unique id for it to be referenced back to. Such as when loaded from a shared link which might look like

> example.com/post/e8a42f290fd853daa666aeaefa607f42

Except I rather have shorter links.

The ids will probably be a combination of a user's username and the current time.

Although there are similar questions I haven't found one that provide answers that I think are best, most suggest using md5 then trim it down, except that would higher the chances of the same string being generated.

**Edit:**

I am not using auto increment because it will become harder to scale later on.

Comment: why would you want to do that? why not just use an auto_incremented method; I assume you're using a database for this?

Comment: For a fully unique identifier, try generating a GUID. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163679/823549

Comment: `bin2hex(random_bytes($id_length/2));` donezo.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sequence generators are easy to start with, but are very difficult to scale effectively. Large, random[ish] IDs are somewhat more difficult to start with, but scale wonderfully.

Comment: @Sammitch `random_bytes()` is PHP 7 exclusive, as a side note ;-)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner that's what [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) is for. :P

Comment: I see @Sammitch B-)

Comment: `$unique = substr(uniqid(rand(), true), 16, 16); // 16 characters long`

Comment: @Daniel I like your forethought. You might want to put in a bit more legwork to define your scaling strategy now, and potentially design your IDs to match. [Pinterest put out an interesting article](https://medium.com/@Pinterest_Engineering/sharding-pinterest-how-we-scaled-our-mysql-fleet-3f341e96ca6f) about their sharding and ID generation which, while not something I would specifically recommend, contains quite a bit of food for thought.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846202/php-how-to-generate-a-random-unique-alphanumeric-string

Comment: Use rand()  and append time to generate a random number

Comment: @Sammitch They mention _"Finally, we needed a nice way to generate universally unique IDs (UUID) for all of our objects."_ So you think a UUID would be good, maybe ignore the length since collision seems more important.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Would Scotts last edit in his answer with a length of 32 be good for what I need?

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work for what you want; seems ok. There are other solutions in there also. Btw, how many writes (per second/minute/hour/day..) are we talking here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into `uniqid()`?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php

Comment: Did you read or know of the warning about it?

Comment: Yes, but what you want does not exist. You want short and unique, but you don't want to use MD5...

Comment: I've down-voted your question because unclear expectations "best".

Comment: @bart I have replaced "best" with words more explaining :)

Comment: Please explain why you don't like long md5 hash? And please explain how mission critical it is to avoid collision? Because you seem to prioritize  shortness over collision, but then complain about a low risk of collision...