# How can I generate a secure and unique token to use in an online ticket service?

Tags: php, laravel, cryptography

I need an approach to generate a cryptographically secure and **unique token** in order to use in an online ticket sale service. What issues should I consider to implement and what is the best practice in Php (Laravel)?

Comment: you can use the unix timestamp.

Comment: You can get help from this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26163679/1483629

Comment: @zahidhasanemon You mean the unix timestamp that increments by one each iteration. It's the least cryptographic system you could choose

Comment: What do you mean by "cryptographically secure"? What are you trying to prevent an attacker from doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unique token? install [paragonie/constant_time_encoding](https://github.com/paragonie/constant_time_encoding)

```
Base64UrlSafe::encode(random_bytes(9))
```

---

- In MySQL, an INTEGER(11) UNSIGNED primary key can hold about 4 billion rows. This is equal to 32 bits.
- If you generate 9 raw bytes from a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator (72 bits of possible values), then base64 the result, you will end up with a 12 character identifier.
- 72 bits of possible values means a 50% chance of collision at 2**36 records, according to the birthday problem.

This means you have a 50% chance of only two duplicate random values after about 69 billion records (a far cry beyond your 4 billion storage capacity). This means that you will almost never have a collision. You should still make sure every selector you generate is unique before inserting a new one, of course.

[source](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php)

---

> Note: this is just to answer the question, scroll down for more approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
```

`PHP` bin2hex function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

`PHP` random bytes function : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-bytes.php

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Laravel there is a random string generator built-in

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$random = Str::random(40);
```

More info https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-str-random

I've used something similar before, it's a little extra check to make sure that the token has not already been used before. The chances are so low that this is **almost** unnecessary.

```
$findKey = function() {
    $proposed = Str::random(40);
    if (Thing::where('token', $proposed)->count() === 0) {
        return $proposed;
    }
    $findKey();
 };
 $this->token = $findKey();
 $this->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel build-in provide function which provide us `uuid` so you can use that.
Here is an example of that

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

return (string) Str::uuid();
```

And here is the reference [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-str-uuid)

Answer (score 0):

Go for JWT Auth Token

I think it is the most secure and unique token generator I have. every time, you login to the system, it generates different tokens for one person.

JWT Auth token from https://jwt.io/introduction/